# IEEETran "Accessed on" date with Zotero Better BibTeX

Tags: ieeetran, zotero, better-bibtex

I'm using IEEETran for my article and need to specify an Accessed on date. My references are managed by Zotero using the Better BibTeX plugin. How do I add the date so it appears in the bibliography? At the moment I have added the reference as a Web Page in Zotero.

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible example and also show us how your .bib entry looks like?

Comment: Maybe directly use the `note` field? For example, `note = {Accessed on Jan.~28, 2023},`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export as Better BibLaTeX, it will add the access date as `urldate`. With Better BibTeX, you would either have to use a postscript, or add this to the `extra` field: `tex.urldate = <date>`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.